# Parâmetro inválido no script batch

Tags: windows, script, cmd, batch

Criei o seguinte script batch para impedir que o usuário de excluir alguns diretórios dentro de seu diretório pessoal. Usamos o OneDrive for Business e alguns links simbólicos para que o usuário faça backup na nuvem de forma transparente.

```
set LogFile=%appdata%\PermissaoArquivos.log

if not exist %LogFile% ( 
    echo Iniciando o processo em %DATE% %TIME% >> %LogFile%

    icacls %systemdrive%%homepath%\Documents /deny Todos:(de) >> %LogFile%
    icacls %systemdrive%%homepath%\Pictures /deny Todos:(de) >> %LogFile%
    icacls %systemdrive%%homepath%\Music /deny Todos:(de) >> %LogFile%
    icacls %systemdrive%%homepath%\Videos /deny Todos:(de) >> %LogFile%
    icacls %systemdrive%%homepath%\Desktop /deny Todos:(de) >> %LogFile%

    icacls "%OneDriveCommercial%\Desktop" /deny Todos:(de) >> %LogFile%
    icacls "%OneDriveCommercial%\Documents" /deny Todos:(de) >> %LogFile%
    icacls "%OneDriveCommercial%\Pictures" /deny Todos:(de) >> %LogFile%
    icacls "%OneDriveCommercial%\Music" /deny Todos:(de) >> %LogFile%
    icacls "%OneDriveCommercial%\Videos" /deny Todos:(de) >> %LogFile%
    echo Bloqueio de exclusao de diretorios do OneDrive aplicado em %DATE% as %TIME% >> %LogFile%
)
```

E eu estou batendo a cabeça aqui pq, de alguma forma, ele rejeita o trecho  "Todos:(de)" da primeira linha, gerando o seguinte output

```
Parâmetro inválido "Todos:(de"
Parâmetro inválido "-"
Parâmetro inválido "-"
Parâmetro inválido "-"
Parâmetro inválido "-"
Parâmetro inválido "-"
```

E o primeiro comando icacls não é processado enquanto os outros são. Alguma dica?

Grato

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fatou incluir **@echo off** no início

```
@echo off
set LogFile=%appdata%\PermissaoArquivos.log

if not exist %LogFile% ( 
    echo Iniciando o processo em %DATE% %TIME% >> %LogFile%

    icacls %systemdrive%%homepath%\Documents /deny Todos:(de) >> %LogFile%
    icacls %systemdrive%%homepath%\Pictures /deny Todos:(de) >> %LogFile%
    icacls %systemdrive%%homepath%\Music /deny Todos:(de) >> %LogFile%
    icacls %systemdrive%%homepath%\Videos /deny Todos:(de) >> %LogFile%
    icacls %systemdrive%%homepath%\Desktop /deny Todos:(de) >> %LogFile%

    icacls "%OneDriveCommercial%\Desktop" /deny Todos:(de) >> %LogFile%
    icacls "%OneDriveCommercial%\Documents" /deny Todos:(de) >> %LogFile%
    icacls "%OneDriveCommercial%\Pictures" /deny Todos:(de) >> %LogFile%
    icacls "%OneDriveCommercial%\Music" /deny Todos:(de) >> %LogFile%
    icacls "%OneDriveCommercial%\Videos" /deny Todos:(de) >> %LogFile%
    echo Bloqueio de exclusao de diretorios do OneDrive aplicado em %DATE% as %TIME% >> %LogFile%
)
```

Answer (score 2):

então, de fato o que faltou foi o @echo off...

eu estava tentando rodar o script sem setar o echo pois queria acompanhar a execução.

No fim o arquivo ficou assim:

```
    @echo off
    set LogFile=%appdata%\PermissaoArquivos.log
    if not exist %LogFile% ( 
        echo Iniciando o processo em %DATE% %TIME% >> %LogFile%
        icacls %systemdrive%%homepath%\Documents /deny Todos:(de) >> %LogFile%
        icacls %systemdrive%%homepath%\Pictures /deny Todos:(de) >> %LogFile%
        icacls %systemdrive%%homepath%\Music /deny Todos:(de) >> %LogFile%
        icacls %systemdrive%%homepath%\Videos /deny Todos:(de) >> %LogFile%
        icacls %systemdrive%%homepath%\Desktop /deny Todos:(de) >> %LogFile%
        icacls "%OneDriveCommercial%\Desktop" /deny Todos:(de) >> %LogFile%
        icacls "%OneDriveCommercial%\Documents" /deny Todos:(de) >> %LogFile%
        icacls "%OneDriveCommercial%\Pictures" /deny Todos:(de) >> %LogFile%
        icacls "%OneDriveCommercial%\Music" /deny Todos:(de) >> %LogFile%
        icacls "%OneDriveCommercial%\Videos" /deny Todos:(de) >> %LogFile%
        echo Bloqueio de exclusao de diretorios do OneDrive aplicado em %DATE% as %TIME% >> %LogFile%
        echo Computador %COMPUTERNAME% - Login %USERNAME% - Data %DATE% - Hora %TIME% >> \\ages9\LOGS\OneDrive\BloqueioExclusao.txt 
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

> Se posso sugerir um ***"Experimento"*** .. 
>   Tente ver se dentro do **if**, o **"()"** está interferindo?

**`if exist arq (faz x) else (faz y)`**... o que entendo, vem para explicar a mensagem: **"Todos:(de"**, onde falta o **`)`** no primeiro comando dentro do **`if`** e nos seguintes, faltam ambos os **`()`**...

> Outro ponto, visto em [**resposta publicadas**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25746550/icacls-deny-everyone-directory-delete-permission) no **SO**, seria usar escape nos argumentos **`()`**, como em:

```bat
icacls "myfolder\dummy" /deny *S-1-1-0:^(DE,WA^) *S-1-5-7:^(DE,WA^)
```

> ***Experimento*** ..

Usando o layout do código abaixo, estou substituindo a execução dentro do **`if`** por um **`goto`** seguido de um duplo **`loop`** chamando um **`call`** ...

```bat
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "LogFile=%appdata%\PermissaoArquivos.log"
set "Folders=Desktop,Documents,Pictures,Music,Videos

if not exist "!LogFile!" type nul >"!LogFile!" & goto :_apply_:

Rem Execute outros commandos, existe o arquivo: "!LogFile!"^^!
Rem Aqui entra seus outros commandos...

goto :eof

:_apply_:

echo Iniciando o processo em !DATE! !TIME! >>"!LogFile!"
for %%i in (%systemdrive%%homepath%\ %OneDriveCommercial%\ ) do (
     for %%I in (!Folders!) do set "_Path_Folder=%%~i%%~I"
     call :_deny_:
    )

echo/Bloqueio de exclusao de diretorios do OneDrive aplicado em !DATE! as !TIME!>>"!LogFile!" 
goto :eof

:_deny_:
icacls "!_Path_Folder!" /deny Todos:(de) >>"!LogFile!" && exit /b
echo/ error: "!_Path_Folder!" & timeout /t -1 & goto :eof
```

> **Experimento** usando **Escape**

```bat
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "LogFile=%appdata%\PermissaoArquivos.log"
set "Folders=Desktop,Documents,Pictures,Music,Videos

if not exist "!LogFile!" type nul >"!LogFile!" & goto :_apply_:

Rem Execute outros commandos, existe o arquivo: "!LogFile!"^^!
Rem Aqui entra seus outros commandos...

goto :eof

:_apply_:

echo Iniciando o processo em !DATE! !TIME! >>"!LogFile!"
for %%i in (%systemdrive%%homepath%\ %OneDriveCommercial%\ ) do (
     for %%I in (!Folders!) do set "_Path_Folder=%%~I%%~I"& call :_deny_:
    )

echo/Bloqueio de exclusao de diretorios do OneDrive aplicado em !DATE! as !TIME!>>"!LogFile!" 
goto :eof

:_deny_:
icacls "!_Path_Folder!" /deny Todos:^(de^) >>"!LogFile!" && exit /b
echo/ error: "!_Path_Folder!" & timeout /t -1 & goto :eof
```

> Seu **Código** usando **Escape**

```bat
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set LogFile=%appdata%\PermissaoArquivos.log

if not exist %LogFile% ( 
echo Iniciando o processo em %DATE% %TIME% >> %LogFile%

icacls %systemdrive%%homepath%\Documents /deny Todos:^(de^) >> %LogFile%
icacls %systemdrive%%homepath%\Pictures /deny Todos:^(de^) >> %LogFile%
icacls %systemdrive%%homepath%\Music /deny Todos:^(de^) >> %LogFile%
icacls %systemdrive%%homepath%\Videos /deny Todos:^(de^) >> %LogFile%
icacls %systemdrive%%homepath%\Desktop /deny Todos:^(de^) >> %LogFile%

icacls "%OneDriveCommercial%\Desktop" /deny Todos:^(de^) >> %LogFile%
icacls "%OneDriveCommercial%\Documents" /deny Todos:^(de^) >> %LogFile%
icacls "%OneDriveCommercial%\Pictures" /deny Todos:^(de^) >> %LogFile%
icacls "%OneDriveCommercial%\Music" /deny Todos:^(de^) >> %LogFile%
icacls "%OneDriveCommercial%\Videos" /deny Todos:^(de^) >> %LogFile%
echo Bloqueio de exclusao de diretorios do OneDrive aplicado em %DATE% as %TIME% >> %LogFile%
```

)